# java loading an arraylist from a file

Tags: java

Hello I have a card collecting game where you fight other guys with cards and collect new ones I want to be able to save you deck of cards which is a max of 10 and then load them into the game when the game starts Here is my save method

```
public static void saveCards() {
    try{
        BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("files/cards.txt"));
        for(int i = 0; i < play.p.c.toArray().length;i++){
            bf.write(""+ play.p.c.get(i).x + " " + play.p.c.get(i).y + " " + play.p.c.get(i).id);
            bf.newLine();       
        }

        bf.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I load that string back in and split it into three different intgers

when th file is saved it looks like this:

```
100 10 4
200 10 8
459 10 4
```

the first digit is the x value the second is the y value and the third is the id of the card.

Comment: read the file line by line, split, assign, add to the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would read the file and then split the lines on whitespace and then read the values so:

First reading the file:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("files/cards.txt"))));
```

Then loop over the content in the file:

```
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    //now here process the line
    String[] args = line.split(" ");
    //and then your values
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int id = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    //and now create the card you should know how to do this 
    //And add the card to the board but I don't know how your game works exactly so I can't really help you here. 
    //But this code will be called for every card in the file
}
reader.close();
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

All Lists are Serializable, so you only need one line to write the list, and one line to read it back in:

```
private static final SAVE_FILE = "files/cards.obj";
private List<Card> cards;

// to save
new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(SAVE_FILE)).writeObject(cards);  

// to load
cards = (List<Card>)new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(SAVE_FILE)).readObject();
```